# Nextpagetoken not working as desired

Tags: c#, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

There are a lot of videos in the channel. Where as 'nextPageToken' only
iterates about 570 of them on my code.

Perhaps not a lib issue because the same happens on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list. After about only 10 pages the nextPageToken disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should using channel+playlistItems API to get **ALL** channel videos, not search API.

Kindly check it out on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it.

Example, i set the channel id UCi-Lb1gFer4U7tkqFA1adiQ and part parameter as contentDetails.

the example of response is:

```
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "UCi-Lb1gFer4U7tkqFA1adiQ",
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"NT-fDeVOLsFPouddIzcaWbd0fJw/sQKRHjGLTreNbWWrW3gIojOKiEk\"",
   "contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
     "uploads": "UUi-Lb1gFer4U7tkqFA1adiQ"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
```

Then you know the **uploads** playlist id now, UUi-Lb1gFer4U7tkqFA1adiQ, so you visit

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

Put UUi-Lb1gFer4U7tkqFA1adiQ as the playlistId, then you would able to get all the videos by pagination.

p/s: please provide your channel id, if you still experience the problem

Comment: This works well on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list, I'm getting the total number of videos however, when I do the same in code it only returns the public listed videos and ignores unlisted etc. I'm using the PlaylistItemsResource with exactly the same parameters as on the website.

Comment: Was using a service account and switched to installed app flow. Now I'm getting all videos back inside my code.